# I cannot get NSURL to accept a string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, nsurl

I have a file path in a string. That works no problem. But as I'm going through the debugger, I notice that my url has "unable to read data" as the value. I've tried it several different ways. But the approach I'm using right now is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: myString)
```

I've been all over this site already and I've found no variation of the approach that seems to help.

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and I think Swift is version 2.2 or something like that. I read on one thread that somebody started having this same issue once they upgraded to the current Xcode version I am using.

Comment: show `print(myString)` output.

Comment: what is the content of myString?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `NSURL`. You want the initializer that takes a file path.

Comment: I guess you need to unwrap the url. Put `!` at the end.

Comment: the content of my string is something like "users/joe/desktop/cat.jpg"

Answer (score -3):

If you have Xcode 7.2 and above with swift 2.2 then Replace with

```
let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "")!
```